# Black screen appearing without loading indicator after splash screen in roku scene graph

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working on Roku app using Scene Graph component. 
In my application when i launch application then showing black screen on few seconds between the splash screen to 
the main screen but i want showing loader in between screen. 
it is possible in Scene Graph? 
Please provide suggestion to resolve it.

Comment: Black screen is ok, but not for a few seconds. Is it happening with every app or just yours?

Comment: Yes, It is happening with every Scene Graph app.

Comment: Could be slow device then. I doubt you can change that programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug. To fix this just add

> splash_rsg_optimization=1

to your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this in a recent work I added a progress dialog at the scene.xml (last component to be on top of everything) with a transparent background and by default the visible property is true.

```
<ProgressDialog
  id="ProgressDialog"
  title=""
  backgroundUri="pkg:/images/dialog-transparent.png"
  visible="true" />
```

When the content finishes loading I just hide it

```
  m.ProgressDialog.visible = false
```